# kk2.1.5 gyro bubble is not at centre

Tags: quadcopter

I have a quadcopter controlled through KK2.1.5 flight controller. I have been flying with it without problems, but now i am facing a problem. When i start and arm the kk2.1.5, by giving throttle it starts turning towards some direction with acceleration. I double checked the motor pins locations and all other things, they are correct. When i took a look to the gyro bubble of kk2.1.5 it wasnt at mid of the crosshair. I turned the quad off and then on. I check bubble again it was at centre. now again when i gave it throttle it started turning towards some direction. I checked the again, and it wasnt on centre this time too. So at the armed state the gyro bubble moves away from centre by giving throttle. due to which quad overcorrects itself. Now i have understood that the gyro is off centre due to vibration  of the FC. What should i do to antivibrate it. What material should i keep in between so that vibrations are almost zero.

Comment: Is it just laying on your chassis? Can you not just screw the sensor down?

Comment: i havnt talked about the sensor. and how can it be laying with out screws. it will fall down while flying.

Comment: What do you mean then when you say, "how do I anti vibrate it? **What material should I keep in between so that the vibrations are almost zero** ?" If it *is* screwed down, then how is it vibrating? You are correct in that you haven't talked about the sensor; you have given no information, pictures, part numbers, or anything else, just that you have a problem that your gyro is not level after control on.

Comment: Hi did you solve this problem cause I'm facing same thing on my kk2.15? Thks.